# Algebra generated by point cylinders

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X\equiv\mathbb N^{\mathbb N}$ denote the set of all sequences of positive integers. For a fixed $n\in\mathbb N$ and $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb N^n$, define the “point cylinder” as follows:
$$C_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}\equiv\{ (x_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}\in X\,|\,x_1=y_1,\ldots, x_n=y_n\}.$$ That is, a point cylinder contains all sequences that begin in a given way. Let $\mathscr C$ denote the set of all point cylinders.

---

For any $n\in\mathbb N$, let $\mathscr F_n$ denote the collection of all *unions* (finite or countable) of point cylinders of the form $C_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}$, where $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb N^n$. It is fairly easy to show that $\mathscr F_n$ is an algebra (that is, it is closed under complements and finite unions), and so is $$\mathscr F=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\mathscr F_n.$$

---

What I want to show is that $\mathscr F$ is, in fact, the algebra generated by $\mathscr C$: that is, $$\mathscr F=\bigcap\{\mathscr H\,|\,\mathscr H\text{ is an algebra; and }\mathscr C\subseteq\mathscr H\}.$$

---

I managed to show that the algebra generated by $\mathscr C$ (the intersection on the right-hand side) is included in $\mathscr F$, yet the other direction remains elusive. In fact, I am not even sure it is true. Any input would be appreciated.

---

My attempt:

*The algebra generated by $\mathscr C$ is contained in $\mathscr F$.* Clearly, any point cylinder $C_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}$ is contained in $\mathscr F_n$, so it is contained in $\mathscr F$. Thus, $\mathscr F$ is an algebra containing $\mathscr C$, so it must be at least as large as the algebra generated by $\mathscr C$.

*The algebra $\mathscr F$ is contained in the algebra generated by $\mathscr C$.* It will be sufficient to prove that $$\mathscr F\subseteq\mathscr H\tag{$\star$}$$ whenever $\mathscr H$ is an algebra such that $\mathscr C\subseteq\mathscr H$. To show ($\star$), suppose  that $F\in\mathscr F$, so that $F\in\mathscr F_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$. Therefore, $F$ is a union of point cylinders of the form $C_{y_1,\ldots,y_n}$. However, this union need not be finite: it may be countably infinite. Therefore, even though $\mathscr C\subseteq\mathscr H$ and $\mathscr H$ is an algebra, it is not guaranteed that $F$ will be contained in $\mathscr H$ (unless $\mathscr H$ is a $\sigma$-algebra). If the statement is to be true, I need to show that the union of point cylinders comprising $F$ can be somehow represented in such a way that makes $F$ remain in the algebra $\mathscr H$.

---

Update: the other direction does *not* hold. “I have discovered a truly marvellous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain.”